# website is Not showing Arabic language in menu list

Tags: php, html

i am facing a problem from last 3 days on wards,
    problem is in my menu item  list is not showing in Arabic but content inside website is showing in Arabic what will be the issue........please solve this

```
http://image-dent.com/arabic/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Thid you set encoding well? I don't see in your page source where do you set encoding, but I do see:

```
<html lang="en">
```

I'm not familiar with that language/charset, but it does look suspicious to me.

Also, I don't see that you set UTF8 anywhere.

Try adding this inside your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="ar" />
```

Comment: what i have to add now.....

Comment: Hmm...open some popular arabic website...check out how they do set encoding from code (view page source). And when you save your files (html, php) make sure you save them in UTF8 NO BOM format.

Comment: ok thanku....but i saved in UTF-8 only....